# Filter property on div affecting children

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, which can contain several other divs, that can outstep parent's borders.

Parent `div` has a *CSS* filter `drop-shadow`

```
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
```

So, all children also generate parent's shadow.

Is it possible to mark one of the children `divs` not render the filter drop shadow?
Unortunately, I can't move this div outside parent.

Here's [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NTohiLhxz0F5X5ARalYS?p=preview) with a simple example :

```css
.greenBorder {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: black;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
}
.withShadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.withoutShadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Can this div ignore parent's filter and not generate shadow? */
  -webkit-filter: none;
  -moz-filter: none;
  -ms-filter: none;
  -o-filter: none;
  filter: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="greenBorder">
  <div class="withoutShadow"></div>
  <div class="withShadow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This not possible.**

In the Filter Effects Module Level 1 you can read:

> A computed value of other than none results in the creation of a
>   stacking context [CSS21] the same way that CSS opacity does. All the
>   elements descendants are rendered together as a group with the filter
>   effect applied to the group as a whole. [[source: w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#FilterProperty)]

This means that all children are affected by by the `filter` property the same way `opacity` works.

**Workaround :**

If you can't change your makup, you can apply the filter only to the elements you need it on. In your example, you can replace the black background with a pseudo element and apply the drop shadow to that pseudo element. This will prevents **applying the filter to the parent and affecting all the children**

Example:

```css
.greenBorder {
  position:relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.greenBorder:before{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background: black;
  border-radius:inherit;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
}

.withShadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -moz-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -ms-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  -o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px green);
}

.withoutShadow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 30px;
  top: 25px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="greenBorder">
  <div class="withoutShadow"></div>
  <div class="withShadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations, I can use it.